# How can I modify a SQL Server procedure to wrong syntax

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I want to modify an already existed procedure to wrong by adding a comma to anywhere which may course syntax error. I did this in the SQL Server Management Studio (ssms) by the following steps:

1. Find the target procedure in Object Explorer.
2. Right click and choose "modify"
3. In the query window, add a comma in the parameter list.
4. Execute

Then it showed Error messages. Then I closed the query window and from the Object Explorer reclicked the "modify". I found the comma I added was disappeared. The procedure was fine again, as I had done nothing at all.

It is different from Oracle which I am familiar with. In Oracle if I alter a procedure to wrong, it will be wrong. But in SQL Server, it seems the database will reject my alteration. How can I do this without dropping the procedure and re-creating it with a script already contained the additional comma?

Comment: In SQL SERVER, You can alter the Procedure, but if there's any syntax error, it will not get complied successfully till you resolve the error.

Comment: Even if you drop and recreate it won't save the comma. Neither `CREATE PROC` nor `ALTER PROC` will complete if there is a syntax error.

What is the purpose of what you're doing?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I just want to make it wrong so that the caller (a web server) will throw error information showing what the parameters are the caller send to in the web server console.

Comment: You can raise an error like below, or you can put this line in: `SELECT 1/0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql won't change/create a stored procedure if it does not compile. 
You can use RAISERROR to throw a runtime error that will get returned to the client

```
RAISERROR ('some error message that can even contain some parameters.', 16, 1);
```